# Group select statements

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, select

I have this ugly `SELECT` statement :

```
        Select 'Urbain' as Véhicule, Count( DISTINCT Plaintes.IDEvenements) as Hebdomadaire
        FROM Plaintes join PVehicule on Plaintes.IDEvenements = PVehicule.IDEvenements 
        join EvVehicule on PVehicule.IDVehicule = EvVehicule.IDVehicule
        join Classe_Vh on EvVehicule.IDClasse = Classe_Vh.IDClasse
        join Type_Voy on Classe_Vh.IDTYPE_VOYAGE = Type_Voy.IDTYPE_VOYAGE
        Where Plaintes.Date >= @Sunday AND Plaintes.Date < DATEADD(Day, 7, @SUNDAY) AND Description = 'Urbain'
```

Which gives me this result :

[image]

I need to copy this query a few times and change a simple keyword like `Nolise` to `Scholar` and so..

I know if I just copy it I will get different requests as a result :

[image]

What I would like to have is  one array with everything in it as if it was a single `SELECT` without changing my whole request. Is there an easy way to get to this ?

[image]

EDIT:

Let's say I want to add another column which will have to check another date condition.

Hebdomadaire which means Weekly in english test to see if it's in this week :

```
         Where Plaintes.Date >= @Sunday AND Plaintes.Date < DATEADD(Day, 7, @SUNDAY)
```

I would add an anual column which would test for this :

```
         Where Plaintes.Date >= 2012/01/01
```

How can I make my query so that only weekly test for the first condition ?

Comment: What have tried already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY Description`:

```
SELECT
    Description as Véhicule,
    Count(DISTINCT Plaintes.IDEvenements) as Hebdomadaire
FROM Plaintes
JOIN PVehicule ON Plaintes.IDEvenements = PVehicule.IDEvenements 
JOIN EvVehicule ON PVehicule.IDVehicule = EvVehicule.IDVehicule
JOIN Classe_Vh ON EvVehicule.IDClasse = Classe_Vh.IDClasse
JOIN Type_Voy ON Classe_Vh.IDTYPE_VOYAGE = Type_Voy.IDTYPE_VOYAGE
WHERE Plaintes.Date >= @Sunday AND Plaintes.Date < DATEADD(Day, 7, @SUNDAY)
GROUP BY Description
```

Comment: I have a quick question for you. I'll add it in the Post

Comment: I edited my first question because I encountered another problem but not worth posting another question. Please check if you have two seconds.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select description as Véhicule
    , Count( DISTINCT Plaintes.IDEvenements) as Hebdomadaire
FROM Plaintes join PVehicule on Plaintes.IDEvenements = PVehicule.IDEvenements 
join EvVehicule on PVehicule.IDVehicule = EvVehicule.IDVehicule
join Classe_Vh on EvVehicule.IDClasse = Classe_Vh.IDClasse
join Type_Voy on Classe_Vh.IDTYPE_VOYAGE = Type_Voy.IDTYPE_VOYAGE
Where Plaintes.Date >= @Sunday 
AND Plaintes.Date < DATEADD(Day, 7, @SUNDAY) 
AND Description IN ('Urbain','Scholar','otherthing')
```

Comment: Works perfectly too ! Thanks a lot !

I edited my first question because I encountered another problem but not worth posting another question. Please check if you have two seconds